# Tkinter -- TypeError: retrieve_input() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am getting errors and having trouble retrieving values from the option button, checkbox, and the text area.

TypeError: retrieve_input() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
NameError: name 'checkCmd' is not defined

```
#!C:/Python27/python.exe

from Tkinter import *
import ImageTk, Image

def retrieve_input(event):
  getter = text.get(text)

  getterV = v.get(v)

  getterChk = chkvar.get(chkvar)
  root.destroy()

root = Tk()
root.title('HADOUKEN!')

text = Text(root, height=16, width=40)
scroll = Scrollbar(root, command=text.yview)

text.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

text.grid(sticky=E)
scroll.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='ns')

text.focus()
text.bind(retrieve_input)

v = ""
chkvar = IntVar()
chkvar.set(0)
c = Checkbutton(root, text="CaseIt", variable=chkvar)
c.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)

radio1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Src", variable=v, value=1)
radio1.grid(row=1,column=0)
radio1.focus()

radio2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Dst", variable=v, value=2)
radio2.grid(row=2,column=0)

b1 = Button(root, text="Submit", command=retrieve_input)
b1.grid(row=1, column=2)

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Hadoken.gif"))
panel = Label(root, image = img)
panel.grid(row=0, column=2)


root.mainloop()


if checkCmd.get() == 0:
  print "yes"
else:
  print "no"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a function as the value for a command, the command won't be called with an event object the way it is with a binding. Your function requires an argument but the button isn't giving it one, hence the error.

As for the error about `checkCmd` being undefined... That's exactly the problem. You haven't defined anything with that name.

First rule of debugging: assume the error message is telling you the truth.